Render Layers in the 4.3 Multipass Viewport Compositor
Does the 4.3 multipass viewport compositor support render layers? When I try to combine two render layers (in this example, to always show an object in front), it doesn't seem to preview both layers correctly, or at all.


Cannot find anything official about it, but viewport compositor does not support passes, so I think it's logical to assume it doesn't support layers as well.

As of 4.3 the viewport compositor does support passes. https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.3/compositor/

Sorry, missed EEVEE in the screenshot. Cycles does not yet support passes in Viewport Compositor.

It doesn't seem like support for View Layers in Viewport Compositor was planned.
Post by Omar Emara who is a developer working on the Compositor answered this question in July 2024:


And a question - will it be possible to have access to view layers?

There are no plans for that at the moment.

So it seems there were no plans to work on that at that time and it's not supported currently. It doesn't seem like there are currently any plans to work on that.

You never know if that may change, but thinking logically, View Layers might not be a feature ideally suited for real-time viewport compositing anyway since View Layers are not really rendered simultaneously. It would probably be reasonable not expect this feature any time soon because of practical reasons - how would that even work real time if you can have arbitrary number of View Layers?.. It would hit hardware limits very fast anyway if at all possible. I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't get implemented at all in foreseeable future.
